# how to find out which file contains a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I've taken over a project which involves a lot of javascript (AJAX and whatnot).  In tracking down functions, is there a way to find out which included `.js` file contains a specific function?

I'm hunting through Firebug but can't find where it isolates the specific **file** which contains the javascript function.  What am I missing?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in front of your function and call it like so: `debugger;functionName()`. Then step into the function using the debugger and Firebug will list the source code of the function along with the name of the source file.

Comment: And how would he place a breakpoint in front of a function he cannot find? The only way I know is to open the file containing the javascript and add the breakpoint at the right line number. Are you thinking of something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Web Developer plugin (for FF and Chrome http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) has a "View JavaScript" feature that shows all of the JS that a page is referencing on a single page.  CTRL-F from there to find the function.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler will let you search through all requests, so you could load the page in Fiddler, then search for your function.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1):

Certain text editors, including Notepad++, allow you to search all files in a directory. You can use that to search for "function foo(" and that should pull it up.

Of course, that assumes the function is declared like that. It could also be assigned, which would be a bit more difficult. You'd have to search for something like "foo\s*=" (using Regex search).